# Invoke 'SVN checkout...' from SharePoint 2013 workflow

Tags: svn, sharepoint, workflow

I would like to be able to invoke a svn-checkout command from within a SharePoint 2013 workflow and check the outcome to see if it was successful. How can I accomplish this?

I guess one way would be to develop a webservice/rest server which would listen for an http-call, perform the svn-checkout and then finally pass the status code as a result back to the SP2013 workflow...

Feels a little bit like overkill though.

Comment: I think this answer your question : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105752/can-a-workflow-start-a-console-app-in-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks Rolivares - very useful link!